# How to display image into picture box contain in string

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an image string contain in an XML file and want to convert the string into an image. I have used the following code which is giving error: **Parameter is not valid.**

Code is following which is give above error:

```
    Byte[] data = new Byte[0];
    byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("D:\notimg.txt");
    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(array);
    pictureBox1.InitialImage = null;
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mem);
```

Below is the data contained in XML tag which I need to convert into the image and display into picture box, I have placed the below data into a notepad file and removed the  XML tag . Please, anyone, guide how to display the below data into an image. Thanks in advance.

```
<photograph>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</photograph>
```

Comment: I think that is Base64, decode first to get byte array : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please share any sample code to convert it, thanks.

Comment: Read the link, there is samples from Microsoft. And dont forget to remove the start and end tag "<photograph>"

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have viewed this code and tried it but how can i mention the .txt file which contain picture data in the Microsoft code sample, thanks.

Comment: read the .txt file into string and then decode it to byte array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
  var s = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\file.txt");
  s = s.Replace("<photograph>", string.Empty).Replace("</photograph>", string.Empty);
  var b = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
  using (var mem = new MemoryStream(b))
  {
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mem);
  }
```

Comment: You're welcome. Life is too short, so make it as simple as possible...:=)

Comment: Thanks, God Bless you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's Base64

first convert to byte[]

then use

```
public System.Drawing.Image Base64ToImage(byte[] imageBytes)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    return image;
}
```

then You Will Got image..!:)